# How To Create Popular Post In Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have function show() to display detail of post, here is my code:

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
      //This line code was used to increment post when someone hit the post
      $viewCount = $post->view_count + 1;
      $post->update(['view_count' => $viewCount]);

      $next_id = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->min('id');
      $prev_id = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->max('id');

      return view('site.show', compact('post'))
                                ->with('next', Post::find($next_id))
                                ->with('prev', Post::find($prev_id));
    }
```

But the problem is, when someone refresh the page or hit the post it will increase over and over. My question is how to solve this problem using session or IP address to prevent from the same user?

I got this from laracasts but I do not know how to implement it with my code:

```
$blogKey = 'blog_' . $id;

// Check if blog session key exists
// If not, update view_count and create session key
if (!Session::has($blogKey)) {
    Post::where('id', $id)->increment('view_count');
    Session::put($blogkey, 1);
}
```

Here is the final code which I was modified:

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
        $siteKey = $post->id;
        // Check if site session key exists
        if (!Session::has($siteKey)) {
        // If not, update view_count and create session key
            Post::where('id', $post->id)->increment('view_count');
        //Set the session key so we don't increment for the session duration
            Session::put($siteKey, 1);
        }

      $next_id = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->min('id');
      $prev_id = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->max('id');

      return view('site.show', compact('post'))
                                ->with('next', Post::find($next_id))
                                ->with('prev', Post::find($prev_id));
    }
```

Comment: remove the first 4 lines of your code and use the laracasts code instead and see if it works

Comment: @DhavalChheda thank you for your suggestion it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty self explanatory, but here it is with comments. You are using the session to prevent multiple view counts. See comments below.

```
$blogKey = 'blog_' . $post->id;

//Check if the session key has not been set for the post
if (!Session::has($blogKey)) {

    //If there is no session set, increment the counter
    $viewCount = $post->view_count + 1;
    $post->update(['view_count' => $viewCount]);

    //Set the session key so we don't increment for the session duration
    Session::put($blogkey, 1);
}
```